# Set compile-time warnings in Visual Studio 2008 with "static_if"-like sulution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, macros, compilation, compile-time

I have a big macro, which contains a plenty of strings of code, i. e. casts from one type to another. When one does some changes to initial types in the structure declaration, cast from bigger type to lesser might take its place. Then compiler starts warning:

> warning C4309: 'argument' : truncation of constant value

pointing the line number of macro in my code, telling nothing of the real string and parameter name.
I would like to write a static compiler-time hack, where *msg* will be the casted field name:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#   define DEPRECATE(foo, msg) foo __attribute__((deprecated(msg)))
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#   define DEPRECATE(foo, msg) __declspec(deprecated(msg)) foo
#else
#   error This compiler is not supported
#endif

#define STATIC_WARNING(name, expr, msg)         \
    {                                           \
        struct expr##__ {                       \
        DEPRECATE(void name##(), msg) {}        \
        expr##__() { name##(); }                \
     }; }
```

but first of all I need to have something like "static_if". I mean I should compare initial and final type, and if they are not equal, I will use STATIC_WARNING mentioned above. Is it possible to write something like that in MS Visual Studio 2008. By the way, it doesn't support anything from C++0x. So I can't even use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG, though it needs C++0x to enable messages.

Comment: This isn't exactly a solution, but check out [loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/), Namely, the [static check](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00676.html)

Comment: Actually I need a warning but not an error message of compiler. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Did you try BOOST_STATIC_WARNING?

Comment: @Marc, somehow BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(false) produce no warning at my machine. I have found the same problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-list/ndeO0NFhNE0). Moreover how can one implement "static_if", to raise warning only when the types are not equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact [Andrew](http://ua.linkedin.com/pub/andrii-chemerys/42/31/800) advised me to use template specialization:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#   define DEPRECATE(foo, msg) foo __attribute__((deprecated(msg)))
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#   define DEPRECATE(foo, msg) __declspec(deprecated(msg)) foo
#else
#   error This compiler is not supported
#endif

template<typename T, bool> struct UseDeprecated { UseDeprecated() { T()._(); } };
template<typename T> struct UseDeprecated<T, true> { };

#define STATIC_WARNING(condition, expr, msg)    \
     {  struct expr##__ {                       \
        DEPRECATE(void _(), msg) {}             \
     }; UseDeprecated<expr##__, condition>(); }
```